# AngularJS - why controller is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple code in my app.js file:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('searchHotels', []);

    app.controller = ("PlaceController", function(){
        this.place = shop;
    });

    var shop = {
        name: 'supermarket',
        distance: 100
    };
})();
```

Here is the index.html file's code:

```
<!doctype.html>
<html ng-app="searchHotels">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="PlaceController as placeC">
        <h3> {{placeC.place.name}} </h3>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the output, my {{placC.place.name}} expression is not replaced by the data it was meant to show. It just outputs "**{{placeC.place.name}}**" itself. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: And you are assigning `undefined` to `this.place` as variable `shop` is … undefined in that part of code.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski, nope, on moment call controller function - place already not undefined

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski absolutely correct! Just putting the shop object before the controller made it right, I forgot that JS is only read top to bottom :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular controller definition is a method call, not assignment. Correct code:

```
app.controller("PlaceController", function(){
    this.place = shop;
});
```